# How do I write a pandas dataframe to SQL server table?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I have a pandas dataframe which i want to write over to sql database

```
dfmodwh
date subkey amount age 
09/12 0012  12.8   18
09/13 0009  15.0   20
```

there is an existing table in sql warehouse with the same column names. The table is called dim.h2oresults

I tried

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('dsn=azure_warehouse_dev;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')


from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table, select
dfmodwh.to_sql(name='dim.h2oresults',con=conn, index=False, if_exists='append')
```

But this just gives me an execution error. Is there a way to write to the table through pyodbc instead of sqlalchemy such that if there is a new data everyday in dfmodwh it just keeps appending and not over writing?

Comment: What did the error say?

Comment: @GordThompson 
DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'sqlite_master'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW); [42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are going to want to use `to_sql()`

```
df.to_sql('<Table_Name', con=<Your_Connection>, if_exists='append')
```

Comment: but this will over write the data. i plan to feed the table everyday with new data

Comment: The "if_exists" should allow you to write to this database and simply add the new data from the dataframe.

Comment: i get an error saying     cur.execute(*args, **kwargs)

ProgrammingError: ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'sqlite_master'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW); [42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")

Comment: I'm assuming you changed the '<Table_Name'> and <Your_Connection> to the connection engine and table name within your SQL database?

Comment: import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('dsn=azure_warehouse_dev;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

cursor = conn.cursor()
dfmodwh.to_sql('dim.h2oresults',con=conn,if_exists='append', index=False)  This is my current code